# Using MAX Value from <limits.h> >in template class

Tags: java, c++, c++11, max

I have a Template class for stack like this :

```
#include <limits.h>  // header for max values 

template <class T> class StakMin: public My_Stack<T> {

    My_Stack <T> Min ;
    StakMin(){
    T= INT_MAX;        // <----------- I want to select it according to the T value 
    My_Stack <T>::My_Stack();
    }
    void push(T key){
        if (key < min() )
    {
        Min.push(key);
    }
    My_Stack <T>::push(key);
    }

    T get_top(){
    int value = My_Stack <T>::get_top();
       if(value == min())
          {
              Min.get_top();  
          }
       return value;
    }
    T min(){
        if( Min.Is_empty()) return INT_MAX;  // <------------ I want to select it according to the T value 
        else return Min.peek();
    }
};
```

One solution would be using function with Switch and make decision statically , but I want to know is there any way to act like Templates ,( more flexible )
let me know if is there special way in java or other language .

What would the maximum of a non-numeric type be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is a numerical type, then you need to include `<limits>` and use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

```
T x = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

This applies to C++, of course.

Comment: What would the maximum of a non-numeric type be?

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi: It was a rhetorical question. Your class implied that the type `T` has a maximum, which in turn implies that T is a numerical type. That's why this answer can be stated unconditionally as "You need to include `<limits>` and use std::numeric_limits.

Comment: yep , just to additional info I got my answer and as you see I have accepted the answer , I liked your question :( , do you know your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<limits>` instead:

```
T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

This is specialized for all numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<limits>` instead of `<limits.h>` and then use

T maxVal = std::numeric_limits::max();

[`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)